# Save file into EC2 directly through Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I've made a Lambda function that stores a binary file into S3 and it works fine.
Instead, now I would like to save this file directly into my EC2 instance storage volume .
I searched a lot but I didn't understand if it's possible yet. Do you know?
I've already made an SSH connection (inside the Lambda..) to run SSH commands but I don't how to use in my case and if  is the right way to save my data ...Do you have some idea?

I know that there is possibility to connect S3 to EC2 but first I would like to understand the possibility above..
Thanks

Comment: https://www.transposit.com/blog/2019.12.18-using-lambda-as-an-ssh-proxy/

Comment: Only the EC2 server has access to the storage volume, so if you want to place a file on that storage volume from within the Lambda function, you have to do it through some kind of connection to the EC2 server. If you already have the Lambda function connecting over SSH to run commands on the server then you should definitely send the file over the SSH connection as well. An alternative would be to mount an EFS volume on both the EC2 server and the Lambda function.

Comment: Rather than saving to EC2, it is easier to store the file on S3 and then run commands on the EC2 instance to 'pull' the file from S3. This avoids all sorts of security hurdles and technical challenges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a solution ( Python ):
Using Boto3 and Paramiko package I build an SSH client to EC2, so I move my file to S3 by AWSCLI.
If useful for anyone I post part of code below:

```
import json
import boto3  
import paramiko  

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #My Parameters
    myBucket = "lorem"
    myPemKeyFile="lorem.pem"
    myEc2Username="lorem"
 
    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
    s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
    OutFileName= "lorem.txt"

# PREPARING FOR SSH CLIENT
    try:
        # GETTING ISTANCE INFORMATION
        describeInstance = ec2_client.describe_instances()
        hostPublicIP=[]
        # fetchin public IP address of the running instances
        for i in describeInstance['Reservations']:
            for instance in i['Instances']:
                if instance["State"]["Name"] == "running":
                    hostPublicIP.append(instance['PublicIpAddress'])
        #print(hostPublicIP)
    
        # DOWNLOADING PEM FILE FROM S3
        s3_client.download_file(myBucket,myPemKeyFile, '/tmp/file.pem')
        # reading pem file and creating key object
        key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("/tmp/file.pem")
    
        # CREATING Paramiko.SSHClient
        ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        # setting policy to connect to unknown host
        ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        host=hostPublicIP[0]
        #print("Connecting to : " + host)
        # connecting to server
        ssh_client.connect(hostname=host, username=myEc2Username, pkey=key)
        #print("Connected to :" + host)
    except:
        raise Exception('OPS, there whas a crash preparing for SSH client!!  500 ')    
    
# MOVING FILE INTO S3 
           
        commands = [ 
            "aws s3 mv ~/directoryFrom/"+OutFileName+" s3://"+myBucket+"/"+OutFileName
        ]
        
        try:
            for command in commands:
                stdin , stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(command)
                SSHout=stdout.read()
        except:
             raise Exception('OPS, somethig happends to SSH client. Move  file to S3 didn\'t run  500')
```